# Xamarin app says it's missing CFBundleIdentifier even though I have it in the info.plist

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, info.plist, cfbundleidentifier

I am trying to run a Xamarin app and it gives out an error that the "CFBundleIdentifier" is missing. I looked at the "info.plist" and I can see that it's there.
This is the error I am getting:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(3,3): Error: A bundle identifier is required. Either add an 'ApplicationId' property in the project file, or add a 'CFBundleIdentifier' entry in the project's Info.plist file. (MyCoffeeApp.iOS)
```

This is a screenshot from the "info.plist":
[info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovbLZ.png)

Did someone encounter this? How can I resolve this?

Comment: BTW, I also tried adding this line:
<ApplicationId>com.companyname.MyCoffeeApp</ApplicationId>
To the project file but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue - I had 2 different locations with the same project and the "info.plist" file I had was in the wrong location.